# Is Stack Overflow the proper place to input my code if I wanted a second opinion on it?

Tags: discussion

I'm finishing up writing my first script, and I was curious where I could place my code to have it checked out. This is my first script, and I am new to coding, so I know a lot of my lines may be extra, or there may be a better way to do what I'm trying to do. I know stack overflow is usually used to ask specific questions about your code, but I didn't know if it was a place you could put your code to get a second opinion about it as well. If not, could you guys recommend a site/place for that?

If this isn't the proper place for this question I apologize, if you know the proper/better place to ask this question please let me know. Thank you as always!

Comment: https://codereview.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As Nicolas Gervais notes in the comments, [codereview.stackexchange.com](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) is a suitable place to ask for general feedback on your code. However, I should add that Code Review is only for working code (or at least, code which works correctly as far as you know). Test your code as well as you can before posting it to Code Review.

If your testing discovers a bug and you can't fix it yourself, narrow it down to a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), and ask a question on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 4):

You're right, Stack Overflow is generally better suited to specific problems. For more open-ended Q&A, try [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

For reference compare the on-topic help pages: [SO](/help/on-topic), [CR](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). For an in-depth comparison, see [A guide to Code Review for Stack Overflow users](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5777/207529).